# Where's my epic badge?

Tags: bug, status-completed, daily-reputation-badges

Epic badge description:

> Earned 200 daily reputation 50 times

From my `/reputation` page:

> earned at least 200 reputation on 51 days

I've seen [Is there a bug in Epic badge calculation?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49727/is-there-a-bug-in-epic-badge-calculation), where the suggestion was to wait a few days, since the calculation is not run often, for performance reasons.  I've waited a few days, but still do not have the badge.  What gives?

---

**Edit**

According to [this comment from Nick](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88465/mortarboard-badges-being-awarded-as-a-result-of-bounties-after-recalc/88526#comment219244_88526), the number at the bottom of `/reputation` should match the SQL for the badges, and that any discrepancy there should be reported as a bug.

Popular Demand's answer raises the possibility that suggested edits don't count towards the 200 (for the purpose of the badge).  But, another [comment of Nick's](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88465/mortarboard-badges-being-awarded-as-a-result-of-bounties-after-recalc/88526#comment219240_88526) implies that the system *should* be including suggested edits in the SQL query:

> .. anything (besides association) totaling 200 counts ...

Comment: I think the job for Epic runs tonight (I got mine during a Friday/Saturday night). I have the fuzzy feeling that it only runs weekly. So I'd expect that you'll have yours tomorrow. If it's not there till Monday, there must be something else going on, though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's in the mail!...after the next build that is.  There are a few changes I'm unsure about that aren't mine so not pushing production this morning.

The only badge that was changed to use the new reputation log was Mortarboard, I've just pushed updates to Epic and Legendary as well.  These badges will be a *bit* more lenient than previous because of how we handle deleted content.  Previously you had to get the badge before the post was deleted, otherwise that post just didn't count at all, that's not really cool for something deleted a year later before you hit your 50th/150th day.

The `/reputation` report still doesn't show deleted content (honestly we should probably remove this route), so the counts at the bottom still won't line up exactly.  However, if `/reputation` shows 50+ you should get the badge soon after...if anything the page will under-count 200+ rep days.

Comment: It came through.  Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

I just looked over your rep graph and saw only 49 days on which you earned 200 or more reputation from vote-type sources. You're one short.

On March 25, you went over 200 only because of the account association bonus, which isn't a vote and therefore doesn't count for the badge. On April 24, you hit exactly 200, but eight points came from suggested edits to tag wikis, which are also not votes and therefore also do not count for the badge. Your count of 51 included both of these days.

Supporting evidence for March 25 not counting: you didn't get the Mortarboard badge that day. You did get it on April 1, the first time you reached 200 rep in one day without the association bonus.

EDIT:
Hmm, that comment by Nick is interesting. It does seem to say that suggested edit rep should count. On the other hand, it also says the SQL isn't changing. The SQL was probably written before edit suggestors earned rep for their work, although the comment was not... perhaps a coding oversight, there?

I also thought maybe I miscounted, but I just went through again and got the same number.

Comment: See my edit above.  Note that the total of 51 on my /reputation page does *not* include the day I got the association bonus (the total would be 52 including that day).  If suggested edits aren't being counted, then I'd still propose that this is a bug, at least according to my reading of Nick's comments on the post that animuson linked to.

Comment: @dbaseman: The SE team is not maintaining the /reputation page anymore. They had originally stated it would be completely removed, and I expect it [still] will be at some point. So anything with that page is probably not a bug, more just a "who cares." A friendly note: don't trigger reputation recalcs on that page, you may lose some reputation and not be able to get it back, because that page runs off of old logic.

Answer (score -1):

The epic badge will be awarded if you hit 50 times the reputation cap. It will not be awarded if you just hit 200 points a day for 50 days.

Example:
You earned 190 points from upvotes and 15 points from 1 accepted answer. That makes 205 points but you did not hit the rep cap since you still can get 1 upvote that increases your rep because bounty and accepted answer points don't count into the rep cap.

Comment: If that's the case, then why isn't the badge description *"reached the daily reputation cap 50 times"*?  The description *"earned 200 daily reputation 50 times"* isn't really ambiguous, and it doesn't equate to what you described here -- are you saying the badge description is simply wrong?

Comment: According to [this answer by Nick](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/88526), the badges were *always* awarded for simply reaching 200 reputation for the day, and *never* had anything to do with the reputation cap.

Comment: @animuson, I just bookmarked that. Thanks. Those are the most confusing badges in the system, IMHO.