# "Epic" badge tracking inconsistency

Tags: bug, badges, daily-reputation-badges, badge-progress

I spotted an inconsistency in the Epic badge tracker:

[image: Epic badge tracker]

It says I earned 30 rep today, except my rep tab says:

[image: Today's rep]

So the *today's rep* bar should have been filled. Looks like it doesn't take bounties into account.

<strike>I can certainly [blame caching](http://shouldiblamecaching.com/) for the missing accept, but the bounty was actually awarded *before* the upvotes.</strike>

**Update:** Well, actually caching isn't to blame, as accepts don't seem to count either.

---

For the record, I counted 33 qualifying days in my reputation graph, so today was correctly counted in the *days earned* bar, even though my `/reputation` page says:

```
earned at least 200 reputation on 32 days
```

(but I'm aware there are inconsistencies between the two already).

Comment: Just curious... do you know if Epic badge stats is a live sync?

Comment: @HackerKarma what do you mean exactly by *live sync*?

Comment: What I mean by is: lets say your at 190 points and if someone upvotes your post and that now takes you to 200 points, then if you go to Epic badge tracker, does this gets reflected? If not then, it means its not live sync.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/49735/230506, And: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/88526/230506, although these answers were 5 and 4 years ago and the system might have changed since then. Maybe wait for someone to comment/answer who actually knows how the current system actually works.

Comment: @HackerKarma just got some more upvotes, and the tracker updated instantly. And accepts don't seem to count towards the goal either.

Comment: That's strange... I am stumped... Don't know what to say here

Answer (score 3):

Originally only rep from upvotes, downvotes and suggested edits counted towards the Mortarboard, Epic and Legendary badges. So reaching 200 rep under this rule was really the maximum. However this was changed.

I guess that they forgot to change the working of the bar as well. This is happening to me too.

Comment: But the badge tracker is a much more recent addition IIRC.

Answer (score 2):

The rep tracker only counts rep that goes toward the rep cap. What? Bounties and accepts do not count towards the rep cap and thus does not count into the rep tracker.

Unfortunately, the rep tracker will only count rep earned from upvotes, edits if you have less than 2k rep, and even downvotes. Yes, even downvotes.

Comment: Yes, but accepts and bounties do count towards the badge, and should be taken into account by the tracker.

Comment: But they are not originally...